# If for every $h>0$, $M_1\leq hM_2+M_0/h$ then $M_1^2\leq 4M_0 M_2$?

Tags: real-analysis

This is the last step of my proof and I'm not sure how to prove it. Can anybody help with this please?

Comment: I think your original question is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98320/if-m-0-m-1-and-m-2-are-least-upper-bounds-of-fx-fx-and-f?rq=1. Note the sentence: *otherwise taking $h = \sqrt{M_0/M_2}$ gives the bound.* That is, assuming that all $M$'s are positive.

Comment: Thanks, could you share any search trick in mse?

Comment: One such way is approach0.xyz; however I found yours by glancing at the "Related" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Rewrite it: $f(h) = M_2h^2 - hM_1 + M_0 \ge 0, \forall h > 0\implies f(\frac{M_1}{2M_2}) \ge 0 \implies M_2\cdot (\dfrac{M_1}{2M_2})^2- \dfrac{M_1^2}{2M_2}+M_0\ge 0 \implies \dfrac{M_1^2}{4M_2}-\dfrac{M_1^2}{2M_2}+M_0\ge 0\implies M_0 - \dfrac{M_1^2}{4M_2} \ge 0\implies 4M_0M_2 - M_1^2 \ge 0\implies 4M_0M_2 \ge M_1^2. $

Comment: Another simple way to put it is that the discriminant of $f(h)$ is non-positive. So, $M_1^2-4M_0M_2\le0$